# why > is getting changed &gt in Unix while executing curl command using Java

Tags: java, unix, curl, io-redirection

I have a requirement that I need to convert the AEM / CQ page properties into XML and download to the locale storage on the server. 
I have converted the page properties into XML and for downloading I am using curl command and executing the command though java Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command). It is working on windows but creating a problem on Unix. Below is my command "curl -u id:password http://serveraddress:4502/content/mypage.xml>mypage.xml"
When running my program on server which on Unix box below error is getting

```
> <head><title>404 Resource at
> '/content/mypage.xml&gt;mypage.xml>mypage.xml' not found: No resource
> found</title></head> <body> <h1>Resource at
> '//content/mypage.xml&gt;mypage.xml&gt;mypage.xml' not found: No
> resource found</h1> <p>Cannot serve request to
> /content/mypage.xml&gt;mypage.xml&gt;mypage.xml on this server</p>
> <address>Apache Sling</address> </body>
```

The ">" is getting converted into &gt.
Please share if you have any idea.

Answer (score 1):

Redirection `>` is evaluated by shell.

So you can execute in java

```
bash -c "curl -u id:password http://serveraddress:4502/content/mypage.xml>mypage.xml"
```

or use [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to capture output of curl without any redirection and write to `mypage.xml` in java.

Answer (score 1):

you could try `curl -u id:password http://serveraddress:4502/content/mypage.xml -o mypage.xml`